# Complete data transfer with dd - Is that possible?

Tags: partitioning, home-directory, external-hdd, dd

I am planning to create a `/home` partition. The only problem is that my hard drive is MBR, not GPT, and I have used the maximum 4 partitions that are available (Windows 7, a NTFS partition for data, Lubuntu 18.04 & swap partition.)

So I came up with a plan: use `dd` to transfer my data, make the necessary changes to the main disk and use `dd` again to restore the data. The plan goes as follows:

1. Boot from a Live CD/USB
2. Shrink the main Lubuntu partition (because the target disk has 73 GB available)
3. Transfer my data with `dd` to the target disk
4. Delete Lubuntu & swap partitions, then create an extended one with 2 "sub-partitions"
5. Restore the data to my main disk using `dd` again
6. Follow [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving) to create a `/home` partition
7. Done!

Is this going to work? Because I don't know if the symbolic links will be transferred and I do not want to spend 2 hours for the packages and updates to download.

Comment: Why 1. do you want a home partition on this drive? 2. do you want to shrink the Lubuntu partition before the transfer of data (risky)? 3. do you want to use `dd` for the data transfer? -- What size of the home partition do you want (Would 73 GB be enough?

Comment: @sudodus 1. In order to not have my data scattered across different drives 2. Yes 3. If it is possible 4. I have about 50 GB used, so 73 would be more than enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Boot from another drive

I would suggest that you work from another drive, for example an Ubuntu live drive or a Clonezilla drive.

- **backup** at least all *files*, that you cannot afford to lose, to another drive before you start shrinking the Lubuntu partition or even better, that you

  - clone the whole current Lubuntu partition with **`dd`** or [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org) or
  - make two tarballs (preserving properties) with

    ```
    cd /path-to-lubuntu-root-file-system/home
    sudo tar                   -cvzf /path-to-external-drive/home.tar.gz .
    cd /path-to-lubuntu-root-file-system
    sudo tar --exclude="/home" -cvzf /path-to-external-drive/root.tar.gz .
    ```

    when booted from a live drive.

### Edit partitions

- Use **`gparted`** to edit the partition table to what you want. If you let the head end of the new root partition be at the same position as the old one, the bootloader will might find it, so that you need not re-install the bootloader (`grub`), if not, it is rather easy to [re-install, 'repair', the bootloader](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing).
- If you rely on the tarballs, you can wipe the root partition and the swap partition, and the editing process will be very fast
- Otherwise you can shrink it by moving the tail end and remove the swap partition
- Create a partition for the root file system at the head end of the unallocated drive space (and leave some unallocated drive space for the other partitions)
- Create an extended partition (using all unallocated drive space)
- Create a partition for `/home` and for swap as logical partitions.

Now you can start restoring data from the cloned image file or the tarballs

```
cd /path-to-lubuntu-home-file-system
sudo tar -xvzf /path-to-external-drive/home.tar.gz
cd /path-to-lubuntu-root-file-system
sudo tar -xvzf /path-to-external-drive/root.tar.gz
```

- Make the UUIDs of the root file system and the swap partition match the lines in `/etc/fstab`
- Create a new line in `/etc/fstab` for the 'home' partition

---

Reboot into your revamped system, and if necessary re-install, 'repair', the bootloader.

---

Screenshot with an extended partition and two logical partitions in it,

[image]

In this case I reduced the size of the `casper-rw` partition of a persistent live drive and added a `home-rw` partition.

Comment: I'll try it tomorrow after school or on Thursday (when I don't have school that day). I'll contact you if I have any issues. Thanks for helping me! Also, I wanted to have 3 partitions inside of the extended one. Why do you suggest that I leave the root partition outside of the extended one?

Comment: Mainly in order to keep the head end at the same position as before (helps the bootloader). If you are ready to re-install the bootloader, you can put it inside the extended partition.

Comment: I think I'm going to do the latter.

Comment: OK, good luck :-)

Comment: Um, no. The backup process went just fine (I chose the tarball method), however, when I went to edit the partition map using GParted, it would not let me add a second extended partition (I already have one). Only primary ones were allowed. Thankfully, I did not save any changes, so now I am left with only the backups and the untouched Lubuntu installation. Any ideas?

Comment: @Bajiru, You need only one extended partition alongside the primary partitions. It is a container, and you can have several *logical* partitions inside it. Try with `gparted` by right-clicking inside the extended partition. I edited the answer to add a screenshot, where there are two logical partitions,  `/dev/sdc5` and `/dev/sdc6`.

Comment: Thank you again! I'll try tomorrow because it's late here in Greece and I'll inform you.

Comment: Hello. I came here to report a problem. I followed the process step by step (used the tarball method), but when I reboot, the boot process is stopped because of an error that says "Partition with uuid=d8???-?????? not found", another that says "error: no such partition found" and the last one that says "error: you need to load the kernel first". Can you help me? Does the fstab need to be "refreshed" in order for the system to recognize it?

Comment: Forget it. I used an older kernel and it booted up successfully. Don't know why, though.

Comment: Congratulations @Bajiru :-)